# ArcGIS Python API FeatureLayer query by buffered point

Tags: feature-layer, spatial-query, arcgis-python-api

I am really running into some problems with the Python API, I am trying to query a feature layer and return all results that fall within a certain distance of a supplied point.

According to the docs here: http://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.features.toc.html#feature what I am doing should work but instead it is just returning 1,000 results each time. I know that it should only be returning 1.

```
pt =  Geometry({"x" : -96.95335386999966, "y" : 32.87209363900047, "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}})

print (pt.is_valid) # True
print (pt.type) # POINT
print (pt) # True

results = policies.query(geometry_filter=pt, distance=10, units="esriSRUnit_Foot")

print(len(results)) # 1000
```

If someone could point me in the right direction to get that to work that would be amazing.

---

The query works with the REST API so I know it is not a problem with the layer or anything like that. It's just something with the Python API

Answer (score 1):

I was able to hack around the problem by wrapping the REST API in python.
This is not the ideal solution but it will have to work for now.

```
def do_buffer_query(url,token,x,y):
    url = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/generateToken"
    payload  = {"username" : "username",  "password" :"password",  "referer" : "www.arcgis.com",  "f" : "json" }  

    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    j = r.json()
    token = j['token']


    url = url + "/0/query" #url of the feature layer
    id_pin_location = "%s , %s" % (x,y)

    payload = {
        "where": '',
        "geometry" : id_pin_location,
        "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",
        "spatialRel" : "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
        "distance" : "10",
        "units" : "esriSRUnit_StatuteMile",
        "outFields" : "*",
        "returnGeometry" : "true",
        "f" : "json",
        "token": token
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    j = r.json()

    return j
```